# Derivation of the spin connection in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spinors, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am  trying to understand the derivation of spin connection from the book "Quantum Field theory in Curved spacetime" by L. Parker and D. Toms.
In chapter 5, page 223, they have written (which I am reproducing)

> $$\omega^a_b = \omega^{\,a}_{\mu\,b}dx^{\mu} \tag{1}$$
>
> $$d\omega^a = e^a_{[\mu,\nu]} dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^\nu \tag{2}$$

Then they compare the above two equations, and come up with the conclusion that

> $$\omega^{\,a}_{\mu\,b} = -e_b^{\,\nu}\left(\partial_{\mu} e^a_{\,\nu} - \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}e^a_{\lambda}\right) \tag{3}$$

Now, I presume while comparing, the authors have replaced the partial derivatives in $e^a_{[\mu,\nu]}$ by the covariant derivative version $e^a_{[\mu;\nu]}$ (as they are both equal). This process introduces the $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ term. But after this, what do the authors do? How do they arrive at the final relation in Eq.(3)?  How does the $dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}$ product disappear?

Note: I am not very comfortable with the form language. An explanation in a non-form language would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that the last equation is for the component $\omega_{\mu}$, whereas the first equation is for the form $\omega$. (You can think of the $dx^{\mu}$ as unit vectors for 1-forms. This is like the difference between the components of a vector $v^{\mu}$ and the vector itself $v = v^{\mu}e_{\mu}$.)

Comment: None of those equations are not sequentially  related to each other but are part of overall derivation showing the spin connection is metric compatible and torsion free. In differential forms this is equivalent to $d\theta^{a}+\omega^{a}_{b} \wedge \theta^{b}=0$. The a and b indices are the orthogonal frame and $\omega$ is spin connection

Comment: Regarding the second equation, it's an exterior derivative of a frame form. Let $\omega^{a}=e^{a}_{\mu} dx^{\mu}$ then $d\omega^{a}=de^a_{\mu} \wedge dx^{\mu}=(\partial_{\mu} e^{a}-\partial_{\nu} e^{a}) dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}$, using the rules $dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\mu}=0$ and $dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}=-dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\mu}$. Note, $\omega$ is the spin connection and $\omega^{a}=e^{a}$ which is a frame form - I could have written it as $e^{a}=e^{a}_{\mu} dx^{\mu}$.

Comment: I forgot a couple of subscripts on $d\omega^{a}$- it should have read: $d\omega^{a}=(\partial_{\mu} e_{\nu}^{a}-\partial_{\nu} e_{\mu}^{a}) dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}$